# Looking for a 1951 paper by Erdős titled "On some problems of Bellman and a theorem of Romanoff", published in J. Chinese Math. Society

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for a copy of the paper "On some problems of Bellman and a theorem of Romanoff", P. Erdős, J. Chinese Math. Soc. 1951. Can someone help me by providing a link or copy of the paper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a digital version of paper [1] in [the list of published papers of Paul Erdős](https://www.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/Erdos.html): click on the title of the reference below and you'll see the same digital object.

**Reference**

[1] Paul Erdős, "[On some problems of Bellman and a theorem of Romanoff](https://www.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1951-08.pdf)", Journal of the Chinese Mathematical Society (N.S.) (1951), 409--421, [MR0072161](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0072161).